# Confused about the point of class member in C++

Tags: c++, member-pointers

Three classes as below：

```
class Base
{
public:
    int var1;
};
class Base2
{
public:
    int var2;
};
class Derive:public Base,public Base2
{
public:
    int var3;
};
int main()
{

    printf("%d %d %d %d %d", &Base::var1, &Base2::var2, &Derive::var1, &Derive::var2, &Derive::var3);
    int Derive::* p = &Derive::var1;
    Derive d;
    d.var1 = 2;
    printf("%d", d.*p);
}
```

The output result is `0 0 0 0 8 2`. I am confused about the result of `&Derive::var1` and `&Derive::var2`. Why they are both equal `0` rather than `0` and `4` respectively ?

Note:I test it with gcc4.7.1 and vs2010. And the results are the same.

Comment: If you think any of them should be equal to something other than zero, you should consider including _all_ of the relevant code... nothing you've posted includes this.

Comment: For pointing to members you should have at least an instance!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You don't need an instance to get a pointer to a member function just to call it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I thought this also at the first glance, but please notice that this is valid syntax. `&Foo::a` will return the **offset** to the member

Comment: @Paranaix I was aware of this, and that it's valid syntax! My way of thinking was: Using _real_ member addresses of an instance should give the OP some clarification.

Comment: @mah @πάντα There is no need to binding a instance to the point of class member. As @Paranaix said `&Foo::a` is the offset of variable `a` in the memory of class `Foo`. Anyway some code is appended and it worked as my expectation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Address of C++ pointer to class data member in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519855/address-of-c-pointer-to-class-data-member-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

As @HerbSutter answered in  [Address of C++ pointer to class data member in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519855/address-of-c-pointer-to-class-data-member-in-visual-studio),:

**The type of `&Derive::var1` is `int Base::*` instead of `int Derive::*`.**

**The type of `&Derive::var2` is `int Base2::*` instead of `int Derive::*`.**