# Why is the value of a pointer-to-member always the same for different members of the same struct?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct foo_s {
    string a;
    string b;
    string c;
};

void print_field(foo_s* foo, string foo_s::* field) {
    cout << "field: " << field << " - " << foo->*field << endl;
}

int main() {
   foo_s my_foo = {
       "a",
       "b",
       "c",
   };

   print_field(&my_foo, &foo_s::a);
   print_field(&my_foo, &foo_s::b);
   print_field(&my_foo, &foo_s::c);

   return 0;
}
```

Its output is:

```
field: 1 - a                                                                                                                                                                                                              
field: 1 - b                                                                                                                                                                                                              
field: 1 - c
```

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the specifics of what's going on in the `print_field()` function.  Namely:

1. What's the type of `field`? I imagine it's `pointer-to-string-foo_s-member`
2. Why is the value of `field` always the same (1 in this case), yet `foo->*field` yields different results?

Mainly, I'm baffled at #2. I imagined field would be an "offset" from the start of the struct and `foo->*field` would have been conceptually equivalent to something like

```
char* ptr = static_cast<char*>(foo);
ptrdiff_t offset = somehow_get_the_byte_offset_from_pointer_to_member(field);
ptr = ptr[offset];
string result = *static_cast<string*>(ptr);
```

but that seems to be out since `field`'s value doesn't vary across calls. What am I missing? How exactly is this specific operation described by the standard?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no overload for `<<` to format the value of a member pointer, so you won't get anything particularly useful if you try. There is an overload for `bool`, and member pointers are convertible to `bool`, so that is what happens here. The pointer isn't null, so it converts to `true`, which by default is formatted as `1`.

To demonstrate further, you could try streaming `boolalpha` first; then you should see `true` rather than `1`.

Comment: Wow, that teaches me to stay with good old printf, and if it is only because I understand it better.

Comment: @martin: That will give undefined behaviour if you try to print a member pointer. C++ I/O is at least typesafe, if sometimes confusing.

Comment: @martin Fun question - what format specifier do you intend to use for the pointer to member? You don't even know the size of the thing (generally).

Comment: @Angew Oh well, may be I should stop writing code ... . For other interested readers,  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519855/address-of-c-pointer-to-class-data-member-in-visual-studio) is the reference.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, that makes sense. I should have understood that's what was going on when `static_cast`'ing the pointer to int triggered a compile-time error.

Answer (score 7):

1. The type of `field` is, as you say, a pointer to a member of `foo_s` of type `std::string`.
2. The value of `field` is `1` in all of these cases, because pointers to member are convertible to `bool`, so when you output them, you get a `1` because they are not null.